# Plotting the columns of a 2D array

Tags: arrays, plot, julia

Say I have a 2D array. The first column contains x values and the second contains y values.

```
arr = [1 0.1; 2 0.2]
```

Outputs:

```
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.1
 2.0  0.2
```

If I want to plot the columns against each other I do so with

```
using Plots    
plot(arr[:,1], arr[:,2])
```

[image]

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Using `plot(arr)` outputs:[image]

Comment: why doing just `plot(arr)` is not enough for you? Does your `arr` have more than 2 columns and you want to plot only the first two of them?

Comment: Hi @BogumiłKamiński. 

I want to plot two points on the same line, these points are (1, 0.1) and (2, 0.2). 

`plot(arr)` plots two lines. I have updated my question to reflect this, hopefully that clears things up :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference `arr` only once you could do:

```
plot(eachcol(arr)...)
```